# Extending from diffrent layouts in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a laravel page which can be extended from admin layout or user layout.
If the user logged as admin it should extend from admin, otherwise it should extend from user.
Can I make this control with a simple if inside of my view like:

```
//in my view
@if(Auth::check())
 @extends('layouts.admin')
@else
 @extends('layouts.outside')
```

If I do this control in my controller I need to make two view for user and admin and I dont want to duplicate my views like:

```
//in my controller
if(Auth::check())
  return View::make('bot/bwin_admin');
else
  return View::make('bot/bwin_user');//the view is duplicated :(
```

So how can I use different parent layout for a view without duplicating that view in laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [control the layout in your controller](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#controller-layouts).

First add the default layout to your controller:

```
public $layout = 'layouts.outside';
```

Then do this in your action:

```
if(Auth::check()){
    $this->layout = View::make('layouts.admin');
}
$this->layout->content = View::make('bot/bwin');
```

Also, you can then remove the `@extends()` from your view. It is not needed anymore since the controller defines the layout.